# Explanation Of The Sandwich Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I know what the sandwich is - it states if we take 2 functions, one which gives consistently greater values than f(x), and one which gives consistently lower values than f(x), if the converge on the same point, then f(x) will converge there too.

But can someone explain to me why this is true? I know there are epsilon delta proofs on wikipedia and such, but that is far too rigorous for me. Is it possible, for someone to explain to me simply and intuitively why the sandwich theorem is true?

Thanks.

Comment: Just draw a picture.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, but how do we know it's true in all situations? You can't draw pictures to show all situations if you see what I mean.

Comment: You know it's true, because of its (very simple) proof. But your question asked for "intuition".

Comment: Suppose that you are driving, that there is a truck on either side of you, and that they both decide to move into your lane. No matter how they perform their lane changes, you will be crushed.

Comment: Think what would happen if $f$ converged to some other limit or did not converge.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x) \to k$ means $|g(x) - k|$ "is small" for "big $x$".

And $h(x)\to k$ mean $|h(x)-k|$ "is small" for "big $x$".

But $g(x) < f(x) < h(x)$.  Where does $k$ fit in.

If $k \le f(x)$ then $|f(x) - k| \le |h(x) - k|$ so $|f(x) - k|$ is also small.

If $k \ge f(x)$ then $|f(x) - k| \le |g(x) - k|$ so $|f(x) - k|$ is also small.

So no matter what, if $|g(x)-k|$ and $|h(x)-k|$ are small and $g(x) < f(x) < h(x)$ for all $x$ then $|f(x)- k|$ is going to be at least as small as one of them.

So $f(x) \to k$.

Now that's not rigorous because we haven't really defined what $f(x)\to k$ means and what $|g(x) -k|$ is "small" means.

But no matter *how* we eventually do define it, it will *always* follow from the definition that $f(x)$ and $k$ are at least as close as either $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is to $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, a function converges to a limit if it gets closer and closer to it. Now it you have two functions converging to the same limit and a third one bracketed between the first two, it has no escape, it must converge to that limit as well.

---

In terms of intervals, for any $\delta$ there is an $\epsilon$* such that

$$L-\epsilon<f<L+\epsilon$$ and $$L-\epsilon<g<L+\epsilon.$$

With $f<h<g$ this obviously implies

$$L-\epsilon<f<h<g<L+\epsilon$$ thus $$L-\epsilon<h<L+\epsilon.$$

*Technically, the $\epsilon$ might be different for $f$ and $g$, but it suffices to take the largest of the two.